# Get elements value by xquery on extended xsd

Tags: oracle11g, xsd, xquery, osb, canonical-schema

I have this canonical structure:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Document">
    <xsd:attribute name="ID" use="optional" type="cdpscm:IDDocument"/>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="NationalID" type="cdpscm:NationalID"/>
<xsd:complexType name="NationalID">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="cdpscm:Document">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Number"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="Passaport" type="cdpscm:Passaport"/>
<xsd:complexType name="Passaport">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="cdpscm:Document">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Number"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Who calls my OSB service will cast if the document is a Passaport or a NationalID, but how I get the number value to pass to another service, for example, if I only have the Document element type which doesn't has the number element.

This is the supossed input:

```
<v24:Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="v2:TouristPerson" ID="5772893">
   <v2:Documents>
      <v2:Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="v2:Passport">
          <v2:Number>03070</v2:Number>
     </v2:Document>
   </v2:Documents>
</v24:Person>
```

The real structure is more complex than this, so probably will need to know if I'm working with NationalID or Passaport, a Tourist or a Native Person.

Using Oracle 11g, Eclipse OEPE.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
declare namespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

let $documents := $body//v24:Person/v2:Documents/v2:Document

for $passport in $documents[@xsi:type="v2:Passport"]
  return data($passport/v2:Number)

  (: similarly for national IDs :)
```

Comment: That test on @xsi:type is sensitive to the choice of namespace prefix. It would be better to use the QName machinery to test on namespace URI. Assuming the data isn't typed, use `$documents[fn:resolve-QName(@xsi:type, .) = QName("namespace-bound-to-v2", "Passport")]`